# MySQL Ordering Lists Question

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have the following code:

```
SELECT    q21coding, COUNT(q21coding) AS Count 
FROM      `tresults_acme` 
WHERE     q21 IS NOT NULL AND q21 <> '' 
GROUP BY  q21coding 
ORDER BY  Count DESC
```

It brings back the following:

```
q21coding                                  Count 
Difficulty in navigating/finding content     53
Positive comments                            28
Suggestions for improvement                  14
Inappropriate content/use                    13
Improve search facility                       6
Include information about staff and teams     5
Content needs updating                        4
Other                                        30
```

You'll notice that Other is the second one down - is there a way of ensuring that Other is ALWAYS at the bottom regardless of the Count size?

Thanks,

Homer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ORDER BY IF(q21coding = 'Other', 1, 0) ASC, Count DESC
```

Comment: Sorry but to further expand on this - if I needed the bottom two to always be Positive Comments and then Other - is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

[@reko_t's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904788/mysql-ordering-lists-question/3904808#3904808) is valid, but actually there is no need to use the [`IF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) function.

In MySQL you can use any expression in the `ORDER BY` caluse and `q21coding = 'Other'` would have been enough:

```
... ORDER BY q21coding = 'Other', Count DESC
```

The `q21coding = 'Other'` expression will return `1` if true, or `0` if false. That will put rows with a `q21coding = 'Other'` at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, add artificial field which is 1 for "Other" and 0 for anything else.
Then do "ORDER BY dummy, Count".